# Swift 3 create game hit before time is up

Tags: ios, swift

I am building a game that I have a random emoji appear in the top corner and another emoji appear on the page. The player should hit the emoji before time is up and when the emoji in the page appears as the one in the corner he is going to lose. I know that I have to make emoji as a button and I created an array of the image. But how can I link both emoji to be invoked each time randomly from my array?

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var myButton: UIButton!

    var timer:Timer?

    @IBAction func pressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let imageArray:[UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "1.png")!,
                                    UIImage(named: "2.png")!,
                                    UIImage(named: "3.png")!,
                                    UIImage(named: "4.png")!,
                                    UIImage(named: "5.png")!,
                                    UIImage(named: "6.png")!,
                                    UIImage(named: "7.png")!,
                                    UIImage(named: "8.png")!,
                                    UIImage(named: "9.png")!,
                                    UIImage(named: "10.png")!]
        let myButton  = UIButton(type: .custom)

        let imageArray:UIImage = myButton.image(for: UIControlState.normal)! as UIImage

        //   let myButton   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom) as UIButton
        myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "10.png"), for: .normal)

        //  button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)

        myButton.addTarget(self, action: "btnTouched:", for:.touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(myButton)
        print ("hi")
    }

    func randomValueBetween(min: Int , max: Int) -> Int {
        var a = min
        var b = max
        if a > b {
            swap(&a, &b)
        }
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(b - a + 1))) + a
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use SpriteKit and add ur emojis as sprites instead of a uibutton??

Comment: what is the difference? sorry but this is my first project

Comment: SpriteKit is generally for game development it's much better suited for games than UIKit

Answer (score 0):

If I am correctly understanding you, you need to randomly show an image of one of your ten images of emojis, and you currently have trouble creating an image appear onscreen. If so, then you need to call `imageArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(10))]` whenever you need to make an image appear.

Comment: exactly. and it connected with the timer to finish the game. I've added timer but how I could link it with the clock image

Comment: I tried this code. 
        imageArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(10))]
        print ("hi").. but still image doesn't appear once I run nothing appears and when I click it shows in output "hi" so he reads from this func